# JSON куда-то пропал (JAVA, JSON, API VK)

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api

И снова здравствуйте...

Есть JSON:

```
{"response":{"count":30,"items":[{"id":31,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1503404720,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Еще одно подтверждение, как здорово заходят хиты даже через 15 лет. Немцы Reamonn в начале 2000-х сделали прорыв со своей меланхоличной \"Supergirl\". В 2017 году их успеть решили повторить Anna Nackab.","signer_id":276417933,"can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456241280,"owner_id":2000147926,"title":"Reamon vs. Anna Naclab","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1503404721,"genre_id":1001}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":2,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":30,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480571513,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 1991 году песня Марка Коэна \"Walking in Memphis\" появилась в эфирах радиостанций. За все время своего существования песня \"обросла\" каверами и ремиксами, использовалась в качестве саундтреков к фильмам. И по сей день припев песни является самым узнаваемым! Кстати, и по сей день это один из успешных синглов США и Великобритании.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240538,"owner_id":2000129726,"title":"DJ Smash vs. Marc Cohn","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480571513,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":5,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":29,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480338116,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"В 2000-х хит от группы \"Руки Вверх\" \"Песенка №5\" зазвучала на европейских танцполах в англоязычном варианте. Вот это, действительно оказалось приятным. Русскоязычная песня стала основой для многих кавер-версий и ремиксов от Атлантики до Тихого океана! Как это произошло - в нашей программе!","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240399,"owner_id":2000124826,"title":"Руки Вверх vs. ATC","duration":25,"url":"","date":1480338116,"genre_id":18,"no_search":1,"content_restricted":1}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":7,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":28,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1480337719,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Музыка преображает человека. Напевая любимый мотив, Вы преображаете все вокруг. А припев современной песни так и просится запомнится... А если мотив песни Вы можете вспомнить через несколько лет, то главная задача автора решена - Вы стали его поклонником . Как изменялась одна популярная песня на протяжении нескольких лет. Добро пожаловать в мир программы.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл один на Всех!\"","id":456240300,"owner_id":2000124943,"title":"Frida Gold vs. Gala","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1480337719,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":4,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}},{"id":27,"from_id":-116125443,"owner_id":-116125443,"date":1467535791,"marked_as_ads":0,"post_type":"post","text":"Этой истории уже более 10-ти лет. Для современной музыкальной истории не такой большой срок, но тем не менее, изменения очевидны.  DJ David Guetta еще раз подтвердил свое умение делать хорошие хиты, пусть и на старом материале. Об этом в нашей программе.","can_delete":1,"can_pin":1,"attachments":[{"type":"audio","audio":{"artist":"Программа \"Сэмпл Один на Всех!\"","id":456239491,"owner_id":2000338373,"title":"David Guetta vs. Alice Deejay","duration":25,"url":"https:\/\/vk.com\/mp3\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3","date":1467535791,"genre_id":18}}],"post_source":{"type":"vk"},"comments":{"count":0,"can_post":1},"likes":{"count":6,"user_likes":1,"can_like":0,"can_publish":1},"reposts":{"count":1,"user_reposted":1}}]}}
```

Из каждого Item пытаюсь достать значение поля "text". Для этого решил "упростить" себе задачу. Запрос делаю как обычно:

```
public interface WallInterface {

    @GET("/method/wall.get")
    Call<List<Item>> getresponse (@Query("owner_id") String OWNER_ID, @Query("offset") String OFFSET, @Query("count") String COUNT, @Query("v") String version, @Query("access_token") String access_token);

    }
```

Переработал класс Item.java (удалил лишнее):

public class Item {

```
@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

В коде это выглядит так:

```
    private void getresponse() throws IOException {
            Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
            WallInterface wallInterface = retrofit.create(WallInterface.class);
            Call<List<Item>> call = wallInterface.getresponse("-116125443", "0", "5", "5.52", "token");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Item>> call, Response<List<Item>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        System.out.println("onResponse  - Success: "+response.body().toString());
                        List<Item> itemArrayList = response.body();
                        if (itemArrayList !=null){
                            System.out.println("onResponse  - Success");
                            showWallList(itemArrayList);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("onResponse  - empty");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("onResponse  - not Success");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }

        private void showWallList(List<Item> itemArrayList){
            textView.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", itemArrayList));
        }

public void OnClick(View view) throws IOException {
        getresponse();

    }
```

И традиционный вопрос: ЧТО НЕ ТАК???

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не так? НЕ приходит ответ? Нет нужный полей в объектах? У вас нет никакого вывода в логи в `onFailure` - если есть ошибка - то её там можно распечатать. Предположу, что надо список объектов в ещё один объект обернуть

Comment: Все красиво, но тихо. Нет отображения данных. Чудо прям.

Comment: И не приходит ответ. Да... и response теперь пропал. В прошлом коде он был. Мистика...

Comment: Добавьте в OkHttpClient, используемый для Retrofit `HttpLoggingInterceptor` - это отдельная либа, которая поможет в логи выводить информацию об отправляемом запросе. Возможно что-то прояснится. И повторюсь - использовать более одного раза `response.body()` чревато проблемами. Если надо несколько раз - вынесите в отдельную переменную.

Comment: Не. Что то не туда... Вернусь в код, когда приходил респонс.

Answer (score 0):

Функция, отвечающая за запрос:

```
private void writeResponse(String response){
        try
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++){
                Item item = new Item();

            JSONObject dataodj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item.setText(dataodj.getString("text"));

                itemArrayList.add(item);

        }
            for (int j=0; j < itemArrayList.size(); j++){
                textView.append(itemArrayList.get(j).getText() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, это все же ответ или дополнение к вопросу?